# Google Drive API File Upload Error: “Missing end boundary in multipart body.”

Tags: java, google-drive-api

i am trying to upload a file to google drive without using api because i don't need it. I've used httpClient from apache for connectivity and encoded file to base64 but it is not working. i am getting this error from server:Missing end boundary in multipart body.

data send to server:

Authorization: Bearer ya29.GluYBCda-OrQMw8Oi-Tf4EIGRU1rzU3Rhak5eozujD3uPMTVOExhcfvDw7k1XSMtMGdBJDNdjZW_wlNvwc-VjmknSTWlRWEZ79MiD6rZkqI6A9vqavGZKDOe11mI
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="simple_boundary"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Host: localhost
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_71)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
--simple_boundaryContent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 {"name":"copy.jpg"}--simple_boundaryContent-Type: 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--simple_boundary--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem may be that your start and end boundaries are not on a new line according to this [website](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1.1). I would try putting CRLF's in prior to your boundaries.

> The boundary delimiter MUST occur at the beginning of a line, i.e.,
> following a CRLF, and the initial CRLF is considered to be attached
> to the boundary delimiter line rather than part of the preceding
> part.  The boundary may be followed by zero or more characters of
> linear whitespace. It is then terminated by either another CRLF and
> the header fields for the next part, or by two CRLFs, in which case
> there are no header fields for the next part.  If no Content-Type
> field is present it is assumed to be "message/rfc822" in a
> "multipart/digest" and "text/plain" otherwise.

*(This was edited because I was initially mistaken, I thought that every boundary had to be closed)*